# How to send multiple div element values into MySQL using Ajax and PHP and each div is a single row in the desired table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am working on page where a nurse should add medication with quantity. And she can add as many as she can at the same time. Here is my html and jquery code and a working snippet from [a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44918418/jquery-incrementing-a-cloned-elements-instead-of-cloned-div):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button.clone").on("click", clone);
  $("button.remove").on("click", remove);
});

var regex = /^(.+?)(\d+)$/i;

function clone() {
  var cloneIndex = $(".clonedInput").length;
  $(".rounded").find("#clonedInput1").clone().insertAfter(".clonedInput:last").attr("id", "clonedInput" + (cloneIndex + 1));
}

function remove() {
  $(".rounded").find(".clonedInput:last").remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-4 rounded" style="background-color: #D3D3D3">
  <div class="row clonedInput" id="clonedInput1">
    <div class="col-sm-6 ">
      <label for="diagnosis_data">Medication</label>
      <fieldset class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control select" name="diagnosis_data" id="diagnosis_data">
              <option value="choose">Select</option>
            </select>
      </fieldset>
      <!-- End class="col-sm-6" -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <label for="medication_quantity">Quantity</label>
      <fieldset class="form-group">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="medication_quantity" id="medication_quantity">
      </fieldset>
      <!-- End class="col-sm-6" -->
    </div>
    <!-- End class="col-sm-6" -->
  </div>
  <div class="actions pull-right">
    <button class="btn btn-danger clone">Add More</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger remove">Remove</button>
  </div>

  <!-- End class="col-sm-4" -->
</div>
```

I want to add each row added as a single row into database (MySQL) using Ajax and PHP:

[image]

The problem is that in this script, the div is changing id, so I can't put all of them in a form and each form send it through AJAX to PHP so I can insert each div as a single row in my table in MySQL.

Comment: Why you can't put them in a form?

Comment: How are you sending to server. Are you posting data to some webapi.

Comment: they are in a form but can't know how to make each div be added as a single row into my table. I am using PHP as back-end language with MySQL as database holder. I want to send data through Ajax

Comment: So, where is your ajax? Look into `.serialize()` jquery method.

Comment: I didn't know how to send those data using Ajax